# Shouldn't the 'range variable' from the join return a list with all members that are the same?

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements, union

Don't worry if you didn't understand the question may be I'm not expressing very well anyway so I'll give an example. Given two lists:

```
class PlayingNote {
    public byte actuator;
    public int dropTime;

    public PlayingNote() {
    }

    public PlayingNote(byte actuatorParam, int dropTimeParam) {
        actuator = actuatorParam;
        dropTime = dropTimeParam;
    }
}

List<PlayingNote> activationNotesTmp = new List<PlayingNote>();
activationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(32, 0));
activationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(16, 125));
activationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(12, 250));
activationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(43, 500));

List<PlayingNote> desactivationNotesTmp = new List<PlayingNote>();
desactivationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(223, 125));
desactivationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(239, 250));
desactivationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(243, 375));
desactivationNotesTmp.Add(new PlayingNote(212, 625));
```

And the query:

```
var sameDTNotes =
            (from an in activationNotesTmp
             join dn in desactivationNotesTmp on an.dropTime equals dn.dropTime into sameDt
             from s in sameDt
             select new PlayingNote {
                 dropTime = an.dropTime,
                 actuator = (byte)(an.actuator & s.actuator)
             }).ToList();
```

Shouldn't the 'sameDt' range variable in the query contain a list with all members that are the same? in the example the first list in the 'sameDt' IEnumerable should contain {16, 223} and the second list {12, 239}? so I'd be able to make a selector like down below and compare the members in the list?

```
public static byte AndBynary<T>(this IEnumerable<T> numbers, Func<T, byte> selector) {
    return (from num in numbers select selector(num)).AndBynary();
}

public static byte AndBynary(this IEnumerable<byte> source) {
    byte retaux = 0xff;

    foreach (byte item in source) {
        retaux &= item;
    }

    return retaux;
}
```

The question is how can I get a list containing the intersection with the same droptime and use AndBinary selector to 'merge' the actuator?

final list containing two PlayingNotes:
PlayingNote(16, 125)
PlayingNote(12, 250)

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does `PlayingNode` look like? I mean what field is dropTime and what is actuator?

Comment: Thank you Arin for the quick response. PlayingNote looks like this:

 class PlayingNote {
  public byte actuator;
  public int dropTime;

  public PlayingNote() {
  }

  public PlayingNote(byte actuatorParam, int dropTimeParam) {
   actuator = actuatorParam;
   dropTime = dropTimeParam;
  }
 }

Comment: let me edit the question for you visualize better

Comment: It seems that you want actuator from both pairs right? I mean you want the `join` (not the select at the end) to return {{16, 233}, {12, 239}}? and then call `AddBinary` on each pair. right?

Comment: So the result will look like this {12, 16}?

Comment: Yes a list with two PlayingNotes containing actuators {12, 16} with their respective dropTimes.  It's a fairly simple example because in the system that I'm building the AndBinary might change the actuators value, that didn't happen in the example, but it has to be 'AndBinary' with all pairs that encounters in the join pairs.

Comment: OK got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add GroupBy to query and then Select objects like this:

```
var sameDTNotes =
    (from an in activationNotesTmp
        join dn in desactivationNotesTmp on an.DropTimeParam equals dn.DropTimeParam
        select new { an.DropTimeParam, ActuatorParams = new[] { an.ActuatorParam, dn.ActuatorParam } });
var result=sameDTNotes.GroupBy(p => p.DropTimeParam, p => p.ActuatorParams)
.Select(p => new PlayingNote
{
    DropTimeParam = p.Key,
    ActuatorParam = AndBynary(p.SelectMany(q => q))
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Reza thank you to reply. 'sameDt' is returning just one of the members {223} and {239}.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write this query instead:

```
var result = (from an in activationNotesTmp
              join dn in desactivationNotesTmp on an.dropTime equals dn.dropTime
              select new[] { an.actuator, dn.actuator }.AndBynary()
             ).ToList();
```